# urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 113] No route to host>

Tags: python-3.x, linux, centos7

I'm trying to create a master, agent script where the master gets information out of the agent. Information such as:

- Hostname usage
- CPU usage
- Disk usage
- Memory usage

I have put this in to a function that returns the data. When the data is about to be send I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./agent.py", line 42, in <module>
    send_data(out_data)
  File "./agent.py", line 36, in send_data
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response :
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1346, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 113] No route to host>
```

I checked if there is connection between the two VM's. One's IP address = 192.168.234.2 (master), the others 192.168.234.10 (agent). The routing tabel from the agent shows [routing table agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NDWa.png) and here is a ping between the two [ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBvnu.png)

Agent.py

```py
#!/bin/python3
##importeer onderstaande modules om deze te gebruiken##
import psutil
import socket
import time
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

url = 'http://192.168.234.2/cgi-bin/master.py'
##de output van bovenstaande prints word geplaats in deze variabel om deze in onderstaande variabelen door te sturen##


#De dictionairys worden klaar gezet om gebruikt te worden
def save_data():
    return {
        'machine'   : socket.gethostname(),
        'memory'    : psutil.virtual_memory()[2],
        'disk'      : psutil.disk_usage('/').percent,
        'cpu'       : psutil.cpu_percent()
    }

#De data wordt in de dictionairys gezet
def print_info(out_data):
    print ("Het script heeft gedraaid op: ",time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
    print ('De naam van deze host machine is:', out_data['machine'])
    print ('Het geheugen is ', out_data['memory'],'% in gebruik')
    print ('De schijf is ', out_data['disk'],'% vol')
    print ('Het CPU percentage dat in gebruik is: ', out_data['cpu'])

#de data wordt naar de master verzonden
def send_data(out_data):
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(out_data)
    data = data.encode('ascii')
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response :
        the_page = response.read()


out_data = save_data()        
print_info(out_data)
send_data(out_data)
```

Master.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
###importeren van modules om deze vervolgens te kunnen gebruiken in het script###
import cgi, cgitb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io
import sqlite3

#maak een instance van een field storage
cgitb.enable()
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

#het verkrijgen van data van de velden die vanuit de agent worden opgestuurd.
def get_data():
    system_data = {
    "machine" : form.getvalue('machine'),
    "cpu": form.getvalue('cpu'),
    "mem": form.getvalue('mem'),
    "disk": form.getvalue('disk')}
    return system_data

#print ("Content-type:text/html\n\n")

current_data = get_data()

con = sqlite3.connect('toets_school.db')
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE if NOT EXISTS gegevens ('machine',VARCHAR, 'cpu' float, 'mem' float, 'disk' float)")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO gegevens (machine, cpu, mem, disk) VALUES ('"+str(current_data["machine"])+"','"+str(current_data["cpu"])+"', '"+str(current_data["mem"])+"', '"+str(current_data["disk"])+"')")
cursor.execute("SELECT cpu, mem, disk FROM gegevens WHERE machine = '"+str(current_data["machine"]+"'")
data = cursor.fetchall()

cpulijst = []
memlijst = []
disklijst = []

for info in data:
    cpulijst.append(info[0])
    memlijst.append(info[1])
    disklijst.append(info[2])

#print(data)
con.commit()
get_data()

print (cpulijst)
def chart_cpu():
    plt.plot(cpulijst)
    plt.title("CPU gebruik")
    plt.xlabel('minuten')
    plt.ylabel('percentage(%)')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig("cpu.png")
    plt.show()

def chart_memory():
    plt.plot(memlijst)
    plt.title("Geheugen")
    plt.xlabel('minuten')
    plt.ylabel('percentage (%)')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig("memory.png")
    plt.show()

def chart_disk_usage():
    plt.plot(disklijst)
    plt.title("Schuifruimte")
    plt.xlabel('minuten')
    plt.ylabel('(%)in gebruik')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig("disk_usage.png")
    plt.show()

chart_cpu()
chart_disk_usage()
chart_memory()

print ("Content-type:text/html\n\n")
print ("<center>")
print ('De naam van deze machine is :', machine)
print ("<br>")
print ("<html><head><title>Website HAF sportschool</title></head><body>")
print("<img src='data:image/png;base64,"+str(base64.b64encode(buf.getvalue()).decode('ascii'))+"' />")
print("<img src='data:image/png;base64,"+str(base64.b64encode(buf2.getvalue()).decode('ascii'))+"' />")
print ("</body></html>")


conn.close()
```

I expect that the agent, sends the information is stored in function save_data get passed in to out_data. And that the data gets send in the function def send_data to the master.

Edit: After the commend from Bill Huneke, much thanks for that. The first issue is solved. With the Linux commands:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-service=http --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

I was able to able to curl master.py. Now my issue is that the database on the master is getting filled only with 'None'.

Anyone that know's how to fix this one?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to troubleshoot this by trying to get that URL from outside your Python first.

So, run 'curl http://192.168.234.2/cgi-bin/master.py' and see what you get.  You may have misconfigured the web server at .2 or may have a firewall rule or some other that is preventing talking to the web server.

Edit: clarification - the "no route to host" error is not necessarily an indication that *routing* is the problem.  Misleading, I know.  It may also indicate that the particular port (in this case http, 80) is not reachable / did not respond.  Ping is a good step, but does not fully diagnose this.

### Update (following question change):

I'm glad to hear you resolved the "No route to host" error that you originally asked about.

I understand you are now finding more issues. Reading through the rest of your script, I would say you have many unusual elements which do not look to me like they will work.  I recommend you build your system incrementally. Take everything out of your scripts and just put in one thing and get it working perfectly.  Iterate from there on: put your work in source control (e.g Git) so you can get back to it as you progress.  Keep adding features, add more fields to the database, etc. Take it slowly, build it incrementally. Ask individual questions as you go.

Start by working on a very basic database insert with just one value and one field. If things aren't working, use other tools (as you did with curl) to confirm that the interacting components are really saying the things you think they are saying.  For example, you should look at what is being sent to your server to confirm that the Form data being sent really is well formed and is exactly what your master is trying to parse.

Also, the system you are trying to build is well suited to frameworks such as Django or Flask. Putting you project in one of these will provide guide rails that will lead (eventually) to success.

Good luck

Comment: Yeahhh exactly that was the issue. Firewall... but now I'm left with one issue... That the database on master.py don't get any information.

When I tried to send the data from the agent to the master. The database is getting filled with 'None'.

Any idea how to solve this one :#